# Capitalize Second Word in a String (ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, capitalize

I'm trying to create a method to capitalize the second word in a string. The code below works, but I was wondering if there are other ways to do this:

```
def camelcase(string)
    tmp = string.split
    tmp[1].capitalize!
    tmp.join('')
end
```

Comment: So you want to get the string 'fooBar' from 'foo bar', I got it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
def camelcase(string)
  string.gsub(/\s(\w)/) { |match| $1.capitalize }
end

camelcase("foo bar baz") #=> "fooBarBaz"
```

Or you might wanna take a look at the `camelcase`method that comes with `ActiveSupport::Inflector` (see: http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize)

Answer (score 1):

You could use tap which "Yields x to the block, and then returns x" according to the docs. In this case capitalize! modifies x in place before being returned to the method chain for further processing by join.

```
def camelcase(string)
  string.split.tap { |words| words[1].capitalize! }.join
end

camelcase('foo bar baz')
=> "fooBarbaz"
```

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat - I thought you meant explain it in the answer. Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def camelcase(string)
    string.sub(/\s.*/) { |s|  s.delete(' ').capitalize}
end

puts camelcase("foo bar bas")
=> "fooBarbaz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = "foo bar"
s.sub(/\s(\w)/) { $1.capitalize } # => "fooBar"
```

Comment: OP is calling `join('')`, my guess is he wants to strip spaces from the resulting string.

Comment: @toro2k Just noticed that, thanks. Updated my answer.